# Portrait Orientation Slider (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

I have tried Nivo Slider for this but I find it hard to convert it into a portrait orientation. Is there an easy way for this? I mean, I'm a newbie of this field and I have been working on this for a couple of days. Thanks! I don't have the code, I just want a portrait orientation and the images will actually resize depending on the sliders width and height. Thanks!

P.S I was following this tutorial but I can't make it work.
LINK: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/code-your-own-juicy-tabbed-slider-using-the-nivo-slider/

Answer (score 1):

Use [sudoSlider](http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/), it´s extremely easy, free, and you have [all the examples you may need](http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/demos.html#all-demos)